# Saving file using File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, telerik, docx

I'm using [this library](https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/) for converting HTML to DOCX:

```
private static void ConvertToDocx(string html)
{
    using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (
            WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument,
                WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
            if (mainPart == null)
            {
                mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                var doc = new Document(new Body());
                doc.Save(mainPart);
            }

            HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
            converter.ParseHtml(html);

            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes("file.docx", generatedDocument.ToArray());
    }
}
```

It works like a charm, But it always generate files with a fixed size, for example 3KB. the generated file seems work and I can open it in MS Word. but it doesn't load inside my [control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/richtexteditor/overview) (RichTextEditor) in my application. Is there something that I forgot adding in `ConvertToDocx` method?

Comment: Can that Telerik control normally open DOCX files? The name seems to suggest that it's for RTF.

Comment: Yes, it opens normal DOCX file without problem. when I try to open the generated file using the Telerik control, nothing be will displayed.